# Branch after I made changes?

Tags: svn

I made some changes to code which I was planning on checking in.  I actually need to branch and then commit those changes.  What is the proper way of doing this without losing data (I'll make a backup)?  Note that I haven't only changed files; I have also done renames.  I want to get it right the first time, hence why I am asking here.

Comment: Of course after searching and then posting this I find a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514501/is-there-any-way-to-commit-changes-that-ive-made-to-my-svn-checkout-of-trunk-to

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want the svn [switch](http://www.linxit.de/svnbook/en/1.0/re27.html) command

1. Branch from trunk / HEAD.  (Despite warnings if using Visual SVN)
2. Use SCN Switch to switch to the new branch.
3. Commit working copy changes to the branch.

Comment: I haven't had to use switch, but I was looking into that.  From what I understand it only switches the repository without updating, etc.  So, would this work: Checkout another copy of the trunk, branch that.  Go back to my modified trunk, switch to branch, commit?

Comment: Yep perfect, Branch from the trunk, use svn switch to switch your trunk with the changes on it to your new branch, and then check your changes into the branch

Answer (score 3):

If your changes are in an existing working copy, and you want to use that as the basis for your branch, you can branch from your Working Copy (WC) and get to work. Check out the [copy](http://www.linxit.de/svnbook/en/1.0/re07.html) command to create your branch from your WC.

Sorry for the lack of command line specifics, I'm a pampered TortoiseSVN user!

Comment: Where one might need to add that with TortoiseSVN you can simply use the CopyTo command in repository browser in order to save the checkout for branching.